# In leaflet, how to detect whether a LatLng in current display area?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

As I know,

```
map.project(latlng)
```

can return a point. However, I've no idea about how to tell whether this point is in the current display area of the map..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.getBounds().contains(point);
```

Returns true if point (LatLng object) is in the map view. See the docs: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds